# JSONParser showing error in android app

Tags: java, android, mysql

i m trying to make app that can communicate with mysql (localhost) 
Only problem is Eclipse is showing  JSONParser  Error 
After trying to find solution for error i found this Tutorial  jackson library tho http://jackson.codehaus.org/

i could not found any solution after 2 days digging into android code

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ERROR:  Multiple markers at this line
- JSONParser cannot be resolved 
 to a type
- JSONParser cannot be resolved 
 to a type
```

and this line of code has same error showing

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
```

Please help me so i can continue my app 
help will highly appreciate!
thanks

Comment: Did you import JSONParser?

Comment: @323go
yes, i imported json-simple-1.1.1.jar but on this line 
' JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params); ' 
waiting for reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to parse a JSON string, you do not need to use any `JSONParser` class. The `JSONObject` itself can be used for parsing JSON.

Pass the JSON string to a new JSON object as following:

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response); //response is the JSON string that you get as response
String name = responseObject.get("name");
```

Similarly you can get the values directly from the `responseObject` itself. No need to use any third party libraries. You can find a very good documentation **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)**.

**EDIT:**

I prefer [**Android Asynchronous Http Client**](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) for making web requests.

Comment: i removed  'JSONParser' class but 'JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);' 
i m using url_all_products, other argument for further work to get display of information can u please tell me how to use these argument in your code

Comment: i i imported java-json.jar into my project and now only one error showing 'jParser cannot be resolved'

Comment: In the Android Asynchronous Http Client  link i provided, you will get a full documentation of how to make requests using that library. Include the jar in your project and follow the documentation in that page for getting response. Then you can use JSONObject to parse the response. Try it and if you are having trouble somewhere you can ask it. :)

Comment: i m going through tutorial that you linked in you Answer, i will ask you question if any @Harikrishnan

Comment: @ Harikrishnan T 
i found a good tutorial while running **AsyncTask** class i got this error
  `12-12 07:58:22.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2414): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-12 07:58:22.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2414): Process: com.example.asycclass, PID: 2414
12-12 07:58:22.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2414): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-12 07:58:22.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2414):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-12 07:58:22.056: E/AndroidRuntime(2414):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
`